# Can't compress a recycled bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an issue with recycled bitmap.I have all the null and recycle from the code. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();               
bmp = DecodeImage.decodeFile(imgpath, 450, 450, true);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);     
Image img = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
```

Error message:

```
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9850
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress 
a recycled bitmap
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at 
android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:272)
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at 
android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:896)
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.multiprvt.PDF$1.run(PDF.java:329)
07-12 15:44:11.924: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Decode Class that brings the resolution down for the bitmap.

```
    public class DecodeImage
       {

       //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
         public static Bitmap decodeFile(File bitmapFile, int requiredWidth, int 
    requiredHeight,     boolean quickAndDirty)
   {
    try
    {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapSizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapSizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null,  
    bitmapSizeOptions);

        // load image using inSampleSize adapted to required image size
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapDecodeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
     bitmapDecodeOptions.inSampleSize = computeInSampleSize(bitmapSizeOptions, 
    requiredWidth, requiredHeight, false);
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bitmapDecodeOptions.inDither = !quickAndDirty;
       bitmapDecodeOptions.inPreferredConfig = quickAndDirty ? Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 : 
     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

         Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new 
    FileInputStream(bitmapFile), null, bitmapDecodeOptions);

        // scale bitmap to mathc required size (and keep aspect ratio)

        float srcWidth = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = (float) bitmapDecodeOptions.outHeight;

        float dstWidth = (float) requiredWidth;
        float dstHeight = (float) requiredHeight;

        float srcAspectRatio = srcWidth / srcHeight;
        float dstAspectRatio = dstWidth / dstHeight;

    // recycleDecodedBitmap is used to know if we must recycle intermediary 
   'decodedBitmap'
    // (DO NOT recycle it right away: wait for end of bitmap manipulation process to avoid
    // java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap 
   android.graphics.Bitmap@416ee7d8
        // I do not excatly understand why, but this way it's OK

        boolean recycleDecodedBitmap = false;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = decodedBitmap;
        if (srcAspectRatio < dstAspectRatio)
        {       scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) dstWidth, (int)  
  (srcHeight * (dstWidth / srcWidth)));
            // will recycle recycleDecodedBitmap
            recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
        }
        else if (srcAspectRatio > dstAspectRatio)
        {
            scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(decodedBitmap, (int) (srcWidth * (dstHeight / 
  srcHeight)), (int) dstHeight);
            recycleDecodedBitmap = true;
        }

        // crop image to match required image size

        int scaledBitmapWidth = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        int scaledBitmapHeight = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        Bitmap croppedBitmap = scaledBitmap;



        if (recycleDecodedBitmap)
        {
            decodedBitmap.recycle();
        }
        decodedBitmap = null;

        scaledBitmap = null;
        return croppedBitmap;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
   }

   /**
    * compute powerOf2 or exact scale to be used as {@link   
   BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize} value (for subSampling)
   * 
   * @param requiredWidth
   * @param requiredHeight
   * @param powerOf2
   *            weither we want a power of 2 sclae or not
 * @return
 */
  public static int computeInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int dstWidth, int 
  dstHeight, boolean powerOf2)
  {
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    // Raw height and width of image
    final int srcHeight = options.outHeight;
    final int srcWidth = options.outWidth;

    if (powerOf2)
    {
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        int tmpWidth = srcWidth, tmpHeight = srcHeight;
        while (true)
        {
            if (tmpWidth / 2 < dstWidth || tmpHeight / 2 < dstHeight)
                break;
            tmpWidth /= 2;
            tmpHeight /= 2;
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) srcHeight / (float) dstHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) srcWidth / (float) dstWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
   }

     public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable)
    {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
    {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 
     drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
   }

    public static Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight)
   {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
         Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,                
    false);
    return resizedBitmap;
   } 

   }
```

Not sure where it is getting the recycle bitmap

Comment: What does your `DecodeImage` class do?

Comment: Have a look into the `decodeFile` method of your `DecodeImage` class. Probably it calls `recycle` on your bitmap.

Comment: it lowers the resolution. I will paste it

Comment: does this happen everywhere or just on 4.3?

Answer (score 11):

Your source and scaled bitmaps are identical. Check for equality before recycling the source.

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, ...):
if (src != scaled) {
    src.recycle();
}
return scaled;
```

From the documentation for Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...):

Creates a new bitmap, scaled from an existing bitmap, when possible. If the specified width and height are the same as the current width and height of the source bitmap, the source bitmap is returned and no new bitmap is created.